# Проигрыватель для сайта

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте, не подскажете, есть ли html-код плеера для вставки на сайт, который мог бы проигрывать музыку, по ссылке с файлобменника.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [jPlayer][1]


  [1]: http://www.jplayer.org/

Answer (score 2):

Кроссбраузерно - only flash. С файлообменника действительно не получиться, чтобы получилось  url к звуковому файлу должен приводить к нему а не к файлообменнику. Теоретически если купить платный аккаунт на одном из файлообменников и с помощью curl авторизоваться, получать прямую ссылку на mp3 и отдавать с помощью, например flashvars url прямой ссылки, то должно получится, но есть ли в этом смысл и напишите ли вы это?:)

Answer (score 0):

C файлообменника скорее всего не получится, по причине не прямой ссылки на файлы, на файлообменниках. Проигрыватель можно сейчас уже реализовать средствами `html5` или, как вариант, `flash` или `java` написать/скачать готовый плеер. `flowplayer` можно нагуглить в первых строках, мне нравиться, хотя для более менее большого проекта уже неприемлемо.. ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 вам в помощь! Через него можно устроить хороший плеер.